# Evaluating improper integral expression

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Can anybody please guide me in evaluating this expression, for my research work. I have tried a lot but in vain. Both the integrals involve gamma functions and even wolfram said that the time limit exceeded. There might be some technique or rule applicable or some workaround. I am not a mathematics student and thus i am having quite a hard time. Thanks in advance !!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is $f_m$ ? Is $j^2=-1$ ?

Comment: fm is a constant and yes j^2=-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean $[h(t)]^2$ rather than $h(h(t))$, when you write $h^2(t)$. Also assuming $f_m$ is constant...

Let $I(b) = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} h^2(t) e^{bt} \, dt$. Then $I(-j 2\pi f_m)$ is the numerator and $I(0)$ is the denominator.

$\begin{align}
I(b) & = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} h^2(t) e^{bt} \, dt\\
& = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} t^{4/k} e^{-2at} e^{bt} \, dt\\
& = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} t^{4/k} e^{-(2a-b)t} \, dt
\end{align}$

Let $(2a - b)t = x$. Then $dt = dx/(2a-b)$.

$\begin{align}
I(b) & = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{x}{2a - b}\right)^{4/k} e^{-x} \dfrac{1}{2a - b} \,  dt\\
& = \dfrac{1}{(2a - b)^{1 + 4/k}}\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} x^{4/k} e^{-x} \,  dt\\
& = \dfrac{1}{(2a - b)^{1 + 4/k}} \Gamma\left(\dfrac{4}{k} + 1\right)
\end{align}$

Thus, $\boxed{\dfrac{I(-j 2\pi f_m)}{I(0)} = \left(1 + j\dfrac{\pi f_m}{a} \right)^{-(1 + \frac{4}{k})}}$

Comment: @MVinay. This is a nice solution, indeed. Cheers :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks! I was just typing a comment asking you whether my solution is correct. The answer looked too simple (because the Gamma function cancels right out).

Comment: @MVinay, Dude you are a wizard, thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of work. I do not have the words. Thanks again.

Comment: Also @ClaudeLeibovici, thanks for your time.

Comment: @M.Vinay Just for confirmation, shouldn't the exponent in the answer be -(1+4/k)

Comment: @user160429 Oh, I'm sorry! You're right.